# I want to Hide scroll bar from the toggle menu

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress, woocommerce

Hi there I want to Hide scroll bar only from the toggle menu of my website https://themensoutfitclub.com , i used this css

```
html {
   overflow: scroll;
   overflow-x: hidden;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar {
   width: 0;  /* Remove scrollbar space */
   background: transparent;  /* Optional: just make scrollbar invisible */
}
/* Optional: show position indicator in red */
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
   background: #FF0000;
}
```

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KQDBE.jpg), [When clicked on product subcategory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mwqz7.jpg)but it removes the desktops default right side bar as well hence making it impossible to scroll without a mouse. I have removed the code now plz help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's suppose your toggle menu class name is `toggle-menu`. Then you should style like this

```
.toggle-menu::-webkit-scrollbar { 
        display: none;  /* Safari and Chrome */
 }
```

Note that, above code only work for chrome and safari.
For mozilla and IE10+ use this

```
.toggle-menu {
    -ms-overflow-style: none;  /* Internet Explorer 10+ */
    scrollbar-width: none;  /* Firefox */
}
```

So, the whole code should be like this:

```
.toggle-menu {
    -ms-overflow-style: none;  /* Internet Explorer 10+ */
    scrollbar-width: none;  /* Firefox */
}

.toggle-menu::-webkit-scrollbar { 
        display: none;  /* Safari and Chrome */
 }
```

Comment: Its not working still i tried it as it is and also with the css class which is .ast-menu-toggle

Comment: Can you edit your question and add your actual code?

Comment: the code i used earlier worked but it just made the desktop default scroll bar disssapear too... so itried finfind my css class of menu i think its this .ast-menu-toggle:

Comment: I inspected your website and added this code https://imgur.com/ti1TPQH.
It is working fine. Check here https://imgur.com/aRszVJA